# Modify Param UUID Fine Uploader Javascript Upload Library

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

I'm using [FineUploader](http://fineuploader.com/) in a new project, but the API that returns the information of the media content doesn't have the UUID field. My question is how to modify this param for another field of my JSON object.

To delete an image on my backend, I need to make a DELETE call to this URL:

```
http://my-website.com/svc/media/ID-OF-MY-IMAGE
```

Instead of the UUID param that put the library on the end of the route.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be tracking the UUIDs server side. If you want to send additional data with the DELETE request, you can make use of the [`setDeleteFileParams` API method](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#setDeleteFileParams). Note that these parameters will be added as query parameters to the URL. The path will still contain the UUID, as this is the ID of the resource to delete.

Alternately, your server can override Fine Uploader's chosen UUID by returning a `newUuid` JSON property in the response to an upload request.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ray!

The person that work on the backend makes the change suggested on the documentation of FineUploader to implement a new field called UUID to handle the items as well.